# Minimal Example for dlib SVM using Python/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, svm, dlib

I need to deploy an SVM in a C++ build target system. Therefore I want to train an SVM using dlib with python/numpy, serialize it and evaluate in the target system.

The python documentation for dlib is rather obscure to me, so can anyone help me with this minimal example?

```
import dlib

# My data in numpy
feature_column_1 = np.array([-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3])
feature_column_2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3])
labels = np.array([True, True, True, False, False, False])

# Features
feature_vectors = dlib.vectors()
for feature_column in [feature_column_1, feature_column_2]:
    feature_vectors.append(dlib.vector(feature_column.tolist()))

# Labels
labels_array = dlib.array(labels.tolist())

# Train
svm = dlib.svm_c_trainer_linear()
svm.train(feature_vectors, labels_array)

# Test
y_probibilities = svm.predict(labels_array_new)
```

I get following error for the training:

```
---> 18 svm.train(vectors, array)

ValueError: Invalid inputs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just added an official example for this to dlib.  I was surprised to find it wasn't included when I looked.  It's available here: https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/python_examples/svm_binary_classifier.py.  Here are the relevant details:

```
import dlib
import pickle    

x = dlib.vectors()
y = dlib.array()

# Make a training dataset.  Here we have just two training examples.  Normally
# you would use a much larger training dataset, but for the purpose of example
# this is plenty.  For binary classification, the y labels should all be either +1 or -1.
x.append(dlib.vector([1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3]))
y.append(+1)

x.append(dlib.vector([-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3]))
y.append(-1)


# Now make a training object.  This object is responsible for turning a
# training dataset into a prediction model.  This one here is a SVM trainer
# that uses a linear kernel.  If you wanted to use a RBF kernel or histogram
# intersection kernel you could change it to one of these lines:
#  svm = dlib.svm_c_trainer_histogram_intersection()
#  svm = dlib.svm_c_trainer_radial_basis()
svm = dlib.svm_c_trainer_linear()
svm.be_verbose()
svm.set_c(10)

# Now train the model.  The return value is the trained model capable of making predictions.
classifier = svm.train(x, y)

# Now run the model on our data and look at the results.
print("prediction for first sample:  {}".format(classifier(x[0])))
print("prediction for second sample: {}".format(classifier(x[1])))


# classifier models can also be pickled in the same was as any other python object.
with open('saved_model.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(classifier, handle)
```

However, if you want to use C++ you should just use C++.  Dlib is primarily a C++ library rather than a python library.  The whole point of dlib is to provide a nice C++ API for people who want to do machine learning.  So you would be much better off just using C++ for training.  There are 99 full C++ examples that come with dlib and complete C++ API documentation.  For example, here is a relevant example http://dlib.net/svm_c_ex.cpp.html.

I really should emphasise that dlib's C++ API is much more flexible than the python API.  Really, the point of dlib is to make machine learning easy in C++, the python API for dlib is an afterthought.  In fact, there are a lot of features of dlib that are expressed using things like C++ templates which have no possible correlate in Python (e.g. since python has nothing like C++ templates) and so these features are not exposed to python.  So really, if you want to use C++ then use C++.  **There is no reason to use the Python API if you know how to write C++**.

Comment: Is there an edit?  stackoverflow doesn't show me any edits :/

Comment: He did propose one, which needs acceptance by other users given his rep. I rejected. Current state: your edit only and he removed it if i interpret correctly (nothing to vote anymore)!

Comment: @sascha, ah ok.  Also, just had the wrong syntax on the verbose enable.  Was in a hurry this morning :/

Comment: Oops... i did misread the [docs](http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.svm_c_trainer_linear) once again (used it like you; still find it more common this way). So i was sure verbosity does not do anything based on the task but i just used it wrong. Now everythings cool.

Comment: Following your advice, I now implemented my pipeline in C++ and now have following problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910328/how-to-use-dlibs-lda
Would be great to get a hint!

Comment: Managed to train and save the classifier. Now I want to extract the test error (out-of-sample) error. So, I load the classifier successfully (using pickle), but when I am trying to make a prediction classifier(x_t), where x_t is a numpy array of the test set I got error :

did not match C++ signature:
    __call__(dlib::decision_function<dlib::linear_kernel<dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 1l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout> > >, dlib::matrix<double, 0
l, 1l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>)

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but some remarks:

## (1)

The error you observe is at least partially due to a check [here](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/114d156daee8e11c7e6ebf907e4b147a998226f0/dlib/svm/svm.h#L61).

```
    for (long r = 0; r < x_labels.nr(); ++r)
    {
        if (x_labels(r) != -1 && x_labels(r) != 1)
            return false;
```

**It means:** `labels = np.array([True, True, True, False, False, False])` is wrong, while `labels = np.array([1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1])` is correct.

## (2)

Usually, in most MLlibs, the data-format is (n_samples, n_features) where rows are observations.

When printing out your feature vectors, this looks correct, **but** your code, after the change of (1) will still throw the same error, except when you treat it as the other way around: so the other interpretation is: you got 2 samples of 6 features each. Using this assumption, y needs to have 2 values. Et voilà... at least it's training!

## Code which is not throwing an error (i'm ignoring what it's really doing)

```
import dlib
import numpy as np

# My data in numpy
feature_column_1 = np.array([-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3])
feature_column_2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3])
labels = np.array([-1, 1])  # +1/-1 & size == 2

# Features
feature_vectors = dlib.vectors()
for feature_column in [feature_column_1, feature_column_2]:
    feature_vectors.append(dlib.vector(feature_column.tolist()))

# Labels
labels_array = dlib.array(labels.tolist())

# Train
svm = dlib.svm_c_trainer_linear()
svm.be_verbose = 10

svm.train(feature_vectors, labels_array)
print('k')
```

## (3)

dlib's python-API does not have an `predict()` function. The C++-API has some learned_function attribute used for prediction, but [this](http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.svm_c_trainer_linear) and maybe [this](http://dlib.net/svm_struct.py.html) indicates you have to do that by yourself (probably using `c_class1` and co. as i can't map anything else to something usable from the candidates of the API-doc).

**EDIT:** I was wrong about predict, as dlib's maintainer/developer mentioned in the comments!

<strike>I really really don't like the state of this and would use something else! (or improve dlib)</strike>.

Not sure how to interpret your environment-constraints but:

- [libsvm / liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) are still state-of-the-art for tasks like these and they are build to be used from C++!
- and [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/) is by far the nicest way to do this from python (internally using the libraries above)

Comment: Of course dlib's python api has "predict functions".  You do this: df = svm.train(feature_vectors, labels_array);  prediction = df(feature_vectors[0]);

Comment: @DavisKing I'm sorry. As non-heavy user i was confused by the pythonAPI, the (struct-SVM) python-example and the C++-API way of doing it. Maybe you should add a simple python-example for classic SVMs too. Nice lib!

Comment: Yeah, I'll add this example.  It's conspicuously missing right now :)

Comment: Also, dlib is primarily meant to be used from C++ and has a huge number of C++ examples (e.g. http://dlib.net/svm_c_ex.cpp.html).  No need to use liblinear, which has a less than well documented API.

Comment: You might be right there (never used it in low-level way to be fair) and i really struggle to understand how you could implement so many very different algorithms achieving high-quality implementations, but liblinear/libsvm has (at least) one advantage: it has been extensively tested by many many users over many years! **Sidenote:** i really hate ```svm_c_linear_trainer``` (C++) vs. ```svm_c_trainer_linear``` (Python) at first sight. Maybe a change of name is needed in terms of collisions; but well... (in this case i would prefer a ```py``` :-D)

Comment: The SVM code in dlib is nearly 10 years old and used by a lot of people as well.  So I'm not worried about robustness.  As for names, yes, the names are funny.  This is because the trainers in C++ are templated.  So you can have svm_c_trainer<liner_kernel> or svm_c_linear_trainer<linear_kernel> or svm_c_trainer<rbf_kernel> or whatever.  The python names are trying to reflect the combination of class and kernel selection.

Comment: Thanks for the insights and additional info!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I edited @DavisKing's answer to a measure of certainty by using svm_c_trainer_radial_basis(). Is this correct?

Comment: You're welcome. It seems it's your lucky day, getting the dev of dlib active here :-)

Comment: Yeah I was really surprised oO

Answer (score 0):

When I change your for loop to this (i don't have dlib):

```
for feature_column in [feature_column_1, feature_column_2]:
    print(feature_column.tolist())
```

i get this as result

```
[-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3]
```

I suppose your data should look as follows:

```
[-1, 1]
[-2, 2]
[-2, 2]
[1, -1]
[2, -2]
[3, -3]
```

what you could get with this piece of code:

```
features = [[-1,1],[-2,2],[-2,2],[1,-1],[2,-2],[3,-3]]
for feature in features:
    feature_vectors.append(dlib.vector(feature_column.tolist()))
```

Comment: Almost, I also had to use -1 or +1 as label. And calling .tolist() on a list gives an error.